# Handling configuration files in full stack Java application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, spring-boot, web-ide

In our full stack application (Java+React), we need to handle large configuration files. These configuration files includes both JSON and YAML files. These configuration files store information (say user settings) that may change during application lifetime. We need to provide some way to our customers so that they can change these files and store/fetch them to/from application. We don't want to re-deploy the application for each modification in configuration files.

- Do we have any utility in Java or node.js for this?
- Is there any web-based IDE available that can be easily plugged into our application and allow customers to change the configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a full stack application, meaning you already have a database for the backend. The database would be the most optimal place to store those configurations.

You can have for example a table named `Configuration_properties`, with columns `property_name`, `property_value` and/or FK `user` if different properties apply to different users.

> to provide some way to our customers so that they can change these
> files and store/fetch them to/from application

Changing a property that exists as a row in a table in DB would be much easier and much more efficient than modifying a huge file that exists somewhere.

Comment: These configuration files contains lot of information so storing all into DB doesn't look good to me and this also requires more effort. We already have these files on the system (tenant wise) and just have to provide some way to edit these files from outside. Need to pluggin some sort of WEB-IDE with system or JSON/YAML editor.